# get specific items by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following statement:

```
return articles.Select(entity => new OrderCateringArticleViewModel
{
    ArticleId = entity.Id, ImagePath = entity.ImagePath
})
```

I want to limit the results by a NOT including items where the value HideUntilDate != null and HideUntilDate > today'date. Based on another question I had posted earlier, I was thinking something like:

```
return articles.Select(entity => new OrderCateringArticleViewModel
{
    ArticleId = entity.Id, ImagePath = entity.ImagePath
}).Where(!(entity.HideUntilDate != null && entity .HideUntilDate.Value > DateTime.Today));
```

This does not seem to work, entity is not recognized in the where clause. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ methods takes delegates (or expressions if you're doing queryables).

The delegate of one method in a LINQ method chain does not in any way carry over to the next method in the chain. You need to write each method using the delegate syntax:

```
return articles
    .Select(entity => new OrderCateringArticleViewModel
    {
        ArticleId = entity.Id, ImagePath = entity.ImagePath
    })
    .Where(entity => !(entity.HideUntilDate != null && entity .HideUntilDate.Value > DateTime.Today));
```

Note the addition of `entity =>` inside the call to `.Where`.

This is necessary. The compiler does not carry this delegate parameter over from the `Select` method to the next step.

However, this will now give you another error, `entity` does not have `HideUntilDate`. Why is that?

Because the `Where` delegate operates on the results of the `.Select`, which is a new anonymous object with just `ArticleId` and `ImagePath`.

Luckily the fix is simple, switch the order of the two methods around:

```
return articles
    .Where(entity => !(entity.HideUntilDate != null && entity .HideUntilDate.Value > DateTime.Today))
    .Select(entity => new OrderCateringArticleViewModel
    {
        ArticleId = entity.Id, ImagePath = entity.ImagePath
    });
```

This will filter before constructing anonymous objects.

Answer (score 1):

try this following code

```
return articles.Where(!(entity.HideUntilDate != null && entity .HideUntilDate.Value > DateTime.Today)).Select(entity => new OrderCateringArticleViewModel
{
   ArticleId = entity.Id,
   ImagePath = entity.ImagePath
});
```